# Cannot assign value to a variable in Objective-C for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to use the iOS StackPanel found [here](https://github.com/aaronbrethorst/StackPanel) in my own project.

I have included the Stackpanel.* files in my project, and to test the functionality, I copied the demo code that is included in the AppDelegate file of the original project into my project as the action for a button press. The problem is, I can't seem to set the value of self.stackPanel (or use [self setStackPanel:). Either way, the value of self.stackPanel remains *nil*.

The relevant code sections are below:

```
// From StackPanelAppDelegate.h (copied to MyViewController.h)
#import "StackPanel.h"

@interface MyNavViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
   StackPanel *stackPanel;
}
@property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet StackPanel *stackPanel;
@end

// From StackPanelAppDelegate.m (copied to MyViewController.m)
#import "StackPanel.h"

@implementation MyNavViewController
@synthesize stackPanel;

-(IBAction)myButtonPress:(id)sender
{
   // Doesn't set correctly
   self.stackPanel = [[StackPanel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
   ...
   // More code that adds things to the StackPanel
}
```

I know that the alloc and initWithFrame: methods are working correctly, because I created another StackPanel* and could set its value to the result of initWithFrame:. In other words,

```
-(IBAction)myButtonPress:(id)sender
{
   // This works
   StackPanel* panel = [[StackPanel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
   ...
   // More code that adds things to the StackPanel
}
```

Am I missing something basic here that won't allow me to set a value to the property stackPanel?

The only other thought I have is that the original code does not use ARC, but my project does, so I removed all the `release` and `retain` statements to keep the compiler happy. I'm fairly new to ARC, but could those changes have made a difference?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `-myButtonPress:` in the original is being called?  Set a break point on it to make sure.

Comment: Instead of removing retain/release, add `-fno-objc-arc` to `Targets => Build Phases => Compile Sources => StackPanel.m` to exclude that class from ARC, then try again.

Comment: One more note: shouldn't the frame height be 460 instead 480 (because of the status bar)?

Comment: @JeremyP: yes `-myButtonPress:` is being called. When I used `StackPanel* panel`, that code was in `myButtonPress:`, and it executed correctly.

Comment: @ott--: Added the `-fno-objc-arc`, but still nothing is getting assigned to `self.stackPanel`. Good catch on the frame height though.

Comment: I noticed you have stackPanel marked as an IBOutlet.  Are you using this property in IB?  I gather that you are not since you are creating the StackPanel explicitly in code.

Comment: @PeterCetinski: I was under the impression IBOutlet compiled to `nil`? I eventually would like to use the StackPanel in IB, I just need to get it to work first.

Comment: Ok, then be sure you are not setting this property to nil via IB

Comment: How would I check that? I'm not mentioning it in IB at all right now. Will that set it to nil somehow?

Comment: @jproch: IBOutlet compiles to nothing.  It's purely there as a marker for interface builder when it parses the interface decalrations. If you are not using this property in IB, you can get rid of the IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it worked out. It was more of a debugger issue than an issue with the actual code.

For anyone else who may struggle with a similar issue, here are a few things I learned on this adventure:

Objective-C requires the `self` keyword when using properties. In other words:

```
self.stackPanel = [[StackPanel alloc] init];  // Sets value of stackPanel property
stackPanel = [[StackPanel alloc] init];  // Sets value of stackPanel instance variable
```

These are usually the same, since `@synthesize stackPanel` creates a backing variable called `stackPanel`. The issue came from the fact that the StackPanel code I was trying to use also had a separately declared variable called stackPanel that was masking the synthesized backing variable. So in my case, `stackPanel` and `self.stackPanel` pointed to 2 different memory locations.

I'm not sure what this caused the synthesized variable to be named, but it caused the debugger to not display it correctly.

For a less worthless debugger, go to Product -> Edit Schemes in Xcode, and select Run *Project Name* on the left side. Set debugger to GDB if it isn't already. This should get more useful results while we wait for Apple to finish debugging their debugger.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this? Not sure why would you need to use self?

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet StackPanel *stackPanel;

....

stackPanel = [[StackPanel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same thing as self.stackPanel?  When you say "not sure why you would need to use self", could you explain further?  I'm just trying to understand your point better..

Comment: Tried that, but still no luck.